# reloadComponent method in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

In the help document, it says that:

> Calling this method causes the picker view to query the delegate for new data for the given component.

I added some breakpoints at:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

when I call the `reloadComponent` method but none of them were called. What is the problem?

Comment: did you provide correct index into reloadComponent? try to call reloadAllComponents

Comment: Check if you have connected 'Datasource' and 'Delegate' Connections for pickerView to File's Owner. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I has already set the delegate and dataSource to the File's Owner. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `dataSource` property of the *pickerView* to an instance of a class that implements the [UIPickerViewDataSource protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPickerViewDataSource).

I think the documentation is referring to a "delegate" as in the software engineering design pattern of delegation, as opposed to the property `delegate` of the class which is probably a little misleading.

Comment: i called reloadAllComponents in the viewWillAppear method, is that OK?

Comment: Calling it there seems ok. Have you checked that your dataSource is set up as you expect? Try sticking a breakpoint on the `reloadAllComponents` and have a look in the debugger that everything's as you'd expect (or print out values just before this call using NSLog statements)?